# NSString works with one method but not the other

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, class, nsstring

I have two different methods of trying to grab a variable from another class. The first one, which I would prefer using doesn't work - The second one, which I don't prefer does. Could someone please explain why?

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {

    NSString *someString;
}

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *someString;

- (void)manualSetVariable;

@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "GrabFromAppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize someString;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification  
{
    someString = @"The Variable";
    NSLog(@"In AppDelegate (1): %@",someString);

    GrabFromAppDelegate *getThis = [[GrabFromAppDelegate alloc] init];
    getThis.varSet = someString;
}

- (void)manualSetVariable {        // THIS METHOD WORKS (2)

    someString = @"The Variable";
    NSLog(@"In AppDelegate(2): %@",someString);
}

@end
```

GrabFromAppDelegate.h

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface GrabFromAppDelegate : NSObject {

    NSString *varSet;
    IBOutlet NSTextField *variable;
}

@property(retain, nonatomic) NSString *varSet;

- (IBAction)showVariable:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)manuallyGrabVariable:(id)sender;

@end
```

GrabFromAppDelegate.m

```
#import "GrabFromAppDelegate.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation GrabFromAppDelegate

@synthesize varSet;

- (IBAction)showVariable:(id)sender {

    if (varSet != NULL) {
        [variable setStringValue:[NSString stringWithString:varSet]];
        NSLog(@"Got String Using (1): %@",varSet);
    }
}

- (IBAction)manuallyGrabVariable:(id)sender {     // THIS METHOD WORKS (2)

    AppDelegate *getString = [[AppDelegate alloc] init];
    [getString manualSetVariable];

    if ([getString someString] != NULL) {
        [variable setStringValue:[NSString stringWithString:[getString someString]]];
        NSLog(@"Got String Using (2): %@",[getString someString]);
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is horribly wrong:

```
AppDelegate *getString = [[AppDelegate alloc] init];
```

That allocates an AppDelegate instance, but it's not `[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate]`, so the `getString` instance will never execute the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method and your someString iVar will never get set.  If you'd set someString within an `init` function, `[[AppDelegate alloc] init]` would, of course, call init.   But since `getString` isn't attached to an `NSApplication` instance, there's nothing delegating the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method to it.

If you want to get a pointer to ***the*** application delegate, you can do:

```
AppDelegate *getString = [[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

or, for brevity's sake:

```
AppDelegate *getString = [NSApp delegate];
```

Comment: So by setting either one of those the rest of the code should work?

Comment: If my eyeballs are as thorough as a compiler, yes.  think of the app delegate object as a singleton, and NSApp as the way to get a pointer to thar singleton instance

Answer (score 0):

In second method you are calling method from app delegate and value is set at that time in someString variable and you get response. However if you are setting value for a varibale in appDelegate using an instance the set value will passed to that particular instance of controller class not to all instances. Hence either you create a shared instance of that variable or call that particular instance
 to get the value somestring by showVariable method.

Comment: I tried calling the instance and it didn't work. I'm not sure how to share the instance of the variable. I thought that by making it a property and synthesizing it was enough.

Comment: @CocoaPuffs - it is enough to "share" it, but you create an instance where you never initialize it, because that instance never executes the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method.  See my answer.